# Flat file caching with zero downtime

Tags: php, caching

Every time new content is posted to my site I regenerate the flat file cache for the first 5 pages of my site. This works great and has greatly reduced server load.

The problem is that every time the file cache is regenerated I see a slight dip in traffic, presumably because some small, but not negligible, percentage of the ~2500 people browsing the site see half generated pages.

I'm wondering what a better method for generating these cached pages in php would be without any risk of users seeing half-written pages.

**EDIT:**

Here is the portion of my .htaccess file that determines whether to load a cached file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (user)
RewriteRule (.*)? - [S=3] # Skip the below 2 lines if the above test passes
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/cache_static_html/cache_static_popular_results_1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^popular/page:([2-9])$ app/webroot/cache_static_html/cache_static_popular_results_$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you build the flat file offline, then put it up at the same time the pages with changes go up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony suffers from this same affliction when you do a clear cache. To circumvent this issue we pre-warmed the cache. Consider the following:

- Create temp directory (be sure to set correct permissions): cache_temp
- Add code to recognize a trigger. If trigger is available set cache dir to cache_temp (instead of cache_current). Example trigger via http: http://mydomain.com?prewarm=1
- The code will know to generate all cache files in cache_temp and not cache_current
- Rename cache_current to cache_old
- Rename cache_temp to cache_current
- Delete cache_old

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, I'd set the trigger to 1 before I start the whole rename cache/rename operation and then back to 0 afterwards so that I know to load from the cache_temp directory while the operation is happening? Any idea how I could check for the trigger within my htaccess rules (see my edit on main post for my current htaccess rules)? The idea is to not have to load my framework at all if they should be served a cached file, so being able to handle checking of some trigger (or if cache file exists, file meta data..) within htaccess would be ideal.

Comment: The trigger would only be passed so your code would know that a pre-warm is requested, so you can tell your framework to generate all cache files in the cache_temp dir instead of the cache_curent directory. This way all the cache files are available and ready to be used so you won't be serving partial cache files under heavy loads.

Comment: Not sure about the re-write rules, every request we do goes through the framework, then the framework figures out which cache files to use.

Comment: Looks like I can use your method and in my htaccess use "RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} < 5" so that it loads from a temp cache for a 5 second interval while a cron job regenerates the cache files.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest maybe using a memcache solution. seems you could write your caches pretty quickly and not have to use the flat file method. Go memory!

Comment: make sure to generate the content, before buffering to the user, and cache it.

Comment: I use APC to cache portions of the site for logged in users, but for non-logged in users I skip loading the entire site framework (cakephp). In my htaccess I have it check if the "user" cookie exists and if it does not it rewrites to a cached file of the homepage.